# Javascript references and differences in memory allocation

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, jquery-data

Does the amount of memory allocated to each Javascript reference depend on the object/function its referencing? In other words, if I create a reference to a small object and then create a reference to a large object, how much will the references differ in allocated memory?

For example:

```
obj1 = {foo: "bar"}
ref1 = obj1
ref2 = window
```

What is the difference in memory allocation between `ref1` and `ref2`?

**Why I ask**

I’m storing references using `jQuery.data()` in scoped context elements (see below) and I just want to be more aware of what I’m storing and how much I’m storing. Does `jQuery.data()` store the reference or create a new object? - (Possibly a new SO question)

My Coffeescript class:

```
class Renderer
  constructor: ->
    jQuery("<div/>", {class: "myScope", data: @}).appendTo("body")
```

In Javascript:

```
var Renderer;
Renderer = (function() {
  function Renderer() {
    jQuery("<div/>", {
      "class": "myScope",
      data: this
    }).appendTo("body");
  }
  return Renderer;
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, JavaScript assignments do not copy objects, they copy references. There should be no difference between the `ref1` and `ref2` variables except they're pointing to different objects.

> Does jQuery.data() store the reference or create a new object?

They store the reference, that's the whole point. It won't put a copy or serialisation of the object.